# Azure DevOps Server 2019: condition for task execution

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

In Azure DevOps Services I use parameters to make task execution optional, e.g:

```
...
parameters:
- name: createObj
  displayName: 'Create Object?'
  type: boolean
  default: true

...
jobs:
- job: build
  pool:
    name: Default
  steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.createObj, true) }}:
    - template: ./templates/create-object.yml
```

Azure DevOps Server 2019 doesn't support parameters, any ideas how such condition could be added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Server 2019 doesn't support parameters, any ideas how
> such condition could be added?

Yes, according to [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/941173/facing-a-sequence-was-not-expected-when-applying-y.html) Azure DevOps Server 2019 doesn't support parameters well. So I suggest you can try **conditional jobs/steps** via variables instead parameters, for more details about [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) syntax.

Since parameters are not supported well for now in Azure Devops Server, it's not recommended to use templates in your scenario. (Variables **can't** be used for conditional template). You can expand those steps directly in your `azure-pipeline.yml` file like this:

```
jobs:
- job: build
  pool:
    name: Default
  steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'echo This is first build task'
      condition: {Add your custom condition here in Step level.}
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'echo This is second build task'

- job: test
  condition: {Add your custom condition here in Job level.}
  pool:
    name: Default
  steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'echo This is first test task'
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'echo This is second test task'
```

You can add condition in Job/Step level to determine whether one Job/Step will run.

Examples for two different directions:

1.Define variable(hard-code) in yaml:

```
variables:
  WhetherToRunCmd:true

jobs:
- job: build
  pool:
    name: Default
  steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'echo This is first build task'
      condition: ne(variables.WhetherToRunCmd,false)
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'echo This is second build task'
```

Then the first cmd task will run by default, and it will skip to run when we change the `WhetherToRunCmd:true` to `WhetherToRunCmd:false`.

2.Use [queue time variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#allow-at-queue-time), don't need to define the variable in yml file:

Edit the yaml pipeline and choose Variables:

[image]

Define the variable `WhetherToRunJob` and enable settable at queue time:

[image]

Then use something like this in yml:

```
- job: test
  condition: ne(variables.WhetherToRunJob,false)
```

Then this job will run by default, and skip to run when we change the value to false using `Queue with parameters option`:

[image]

I think the `variables+condition` can also satisfy your needs that run steps/jobs conditionally. Also you can modify the conditions if you want, like and(succeed(),eq(...)...) or what.